# Sha256 is creating wrong hash

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate a `sha256`, and this code seems to be doing it wrong.

```
private static string GetSHA256(string text){
    UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
    byte[] hashValue;
    byte[] message = UE.GetBytes(text);

    SHA256Managed hashString = new SHA256Managed();
    string hex = "";

    hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);
    foreach (byte x in hashValue){
        hex += string.Format("{0:x2}", x);
    }
    return hex;
}
```

I have a server that generates a `sha256` based on data sent to it, and the the value from this `sha256` doesn't match the one on the server. I have tried generating the same using `PHP`, and `JavaScript`, and those both generate the same `sha256` as the server, so I have come to the conclusion that this has to be what is wrong.

with php I am using this:

```
$time = time();
$str = "5550d868c5242fb3299a2604|$time|1431619392-36e2d4f3b5de0bfd5f26e3efabbbd99dc2503dab";

$hash = hash("sha256", $str);
```

Here is what is getting hashed with C#

```
string time = ((DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds).ToString();
GetSHA256("5550d868c5242fb3299a2604|"+time+"|1431619392-36e2d4f3b5de0bfd5f26e3efabbbd99dc2503dab")
```

As you can see they are both the same format, so I think that this is the issue. Can anyone see how I am hashing differently in C#?

Comment: Are you sure you want `UnicodeEncoding`? "Unicode" in .NET land usually means UTF-16. I don't know off hand, but I would expect JavaScript and PHP use UTF-8 by default.

Comment: (It doesn't help that you haven't shown the *expected* result and the *actual* result...)

Comment: maybe not... I found that on stackoverflow somewhere

Comment: Are you using a date in the hashed string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`UnicodeEncoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding.aspx) uses UTF-16 encoding. Your encoding should match what PHP uses, which is probably either [UTF-8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx) or [ASCII](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx) (which are equivalent if you only use the common, simple characters used in your example).

```
private static string GetSHA256(string text){
    byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

    SHA256Managed hashString = new SHA256Managed();

    byte[] hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);
    string hex = "";
    foreach (var x in hashValue){
        hex += string.Format("{0:x2}", x);
    }
    return hex;
}
```

Comment: I believe php uses iso8859, I don't think it matters for op's problem though